# android artifact built in playn deploied but not running

Tags: android, playn

I've installed all the modules in the playn project with maven 3
with no errors.

I deploy via mvn android:deploy
an example in the running android emulator
for instance the showcase,
the deploy finishes without errors, but when I start the deployed app in the emulator it fails with black screen or with an Exception..

What android version is supported ? Do I need to set up the emulator with a particular release ? (2.3.3, 3.1, 3.2 ecc... )

**showcase log**

```
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0
x10200000 cmp=playn.showcase.android/.ShowcaseActivity } from pid 134
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc playn.showcase.android for activity playn.showcase.android/.ShowcaseActivity: pid=2
98 uid=10037 gids={}
D/dalvikvm(  298): Trying to load lib /data/data/playn.showcase.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x405143f0
D/dalvikvm(  298): Added shared lib /data/data/playn.showcase.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x405143f0
D/dalvikvm(  298): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/playn.showcase.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x405143f0
, skipping init
I/WindowManager(   61): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(   61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=3
4 uiMode=17 seq=7}
D/playn   (  298): onResume
I/playn   (  298): notifyVisibilityChanged: 0
D/playn   (  298): Using default sizing.
I/playn   (  298): Screen sized changed to ( 800 , 480)
I/ActivityManager(   61): Displayed playn.showcase.android/.ShowcaseActivity: +1s198ms
D/libEGL  (  298): egl.cfg not found, using default config
D/libEGL  (  298): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
W/dalvikvm(  298): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
D/playn   (  298): Using default sizing.
E/AndroidRuntime(  298): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
E/AndroidRuntime(  298): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
E/AndroidRuntime(  298):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(  298):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:919)
E/AndroidRuntime(  298):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1264)
E/AndroidRuntime(  298):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
W/ActivityManager(   61):   Force finishing activity playn.showcase.android/.ShowcaseActivity
D/playn   (  298): onPause
I/playn   (  298): notifyVisibilityChanged: 4
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  134): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 194K, 50% free 3072K/6023K, external 8206K/8211K, paused 45ms
D/AndroidRuntime(  298): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  298): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
I/Process (  298): Sending signal. PID: 298 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(   61): Process playn.showcase.android (pid 298) has died.
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{407775c8 SurfaceView paused=false}
E/InputDispatcher(   61): channel '4076eb18 playn.showcase.android/playn.showcase.android.ShowcaseActivity (server)' ~ C
onsumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(   61): channel '4076eb18 playn.showcase.android/playn.showcase.android.ShowcaseActivity (server)' ~ C
hannel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{4076eb18 playn.showcase.android/playn.showcase.android.ShowcaseActivity paused
=false}
D/SntpClient(   61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
W/InputManagerService(   61): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 298 uid 10037
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 107K, 45% free 4200K/7623K, external 3906K/4385K, paused 271ms
I/WindowManager(   61): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(   61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=3
4 uiMode=17 seq=8}
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 203K, 50% free 3038K/6023K, external 8162K/8177K, paused 53ms
D/dalvikvm(  171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 346K, 53% free 2767K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 3ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 211K, 53% free 2855K/6023K, external 6083K/7524K, paused 47ms
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 177K, 50% free 3021K/6023K, external 6606K/7524K, paused 96ms
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 46% free 4190K/7623K, external 3897K/4385K, paused 99ms
W/ActivityManager(   61): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{406a61c0 playn.showcase.android/.ShowcaseActivity}


**************************************************************************
cute game log*******************

I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x100
00000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } from pid 0
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc com.android.launcher for activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launch
er: pid=134 uid=10013 gids={}
I/SystemServer(   61): Enabled StrictMode for system server main thread.
E/logwrapper(  137): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
I/logwrapper(   30): /system/bin/tc terminated by exit(1)
E/logwrapper(  138): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
I/logwrapper(   30): /system/bin/tc terminated by exit(1)
E/logwrapper(  139): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
I/logwrapper(   30): /system/bin/tc terminated by exit(1)
D/dalvikvm(  107): GC_CONCURRENT freed 393K, 54% free 2643K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+28ms
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 189K, 44% free 3940K/6919K, external 2729K/2770K, paused 396ms
D/dalvikvm(  111): GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 54% free 2650K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 6ms+107ms
D/dalvikvm(  111): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libwnndict.so 0x40512cf0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(  131): GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 54% free 2640K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 6ms+39ms
D/dalvikvm(  129): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 54% free 2648K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 6ms+96ms
D/dalvikvm(  111): GC_CONCURRENT freed 302K, 51% free 2900K/5831K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+84ms
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 23K, 43% free 3964K/6919K, external 3341K/3347K, paused 465ms
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_CONCURRENT freed 406K, 54% free 2639K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+47ms
I/ActivityThread(  134): Pub com.android.launcher2.settings: com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider
I/ActivityThread(  131): Pub mms: com.android.providers.telephony.MmsProvider
I/ActivityThread(  131): Pub sms: com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider
I/ActivityThread(  131): Pub telephony: com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider
I/ActivityThread(  131): Pub icc: com.android.phone.IccProvider
I/StatusBarManagerService(   61): registerStatusBar bar=com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBar$Stub$Proxy@40637768
I/ActivityThread(  131): Pub mms-sms: com.android.providers.telephony.MmsSmsProvider
D/VoldCmdListener(   29): share status ums
D/StorageNotification(  107): Startup with UMS connection false (media state unmounted)
I/StorageNotification(  107): UMS connection changed to false (media state unmounted)
D/dalvikvm(  111): GC_CONCURRENT freed 399K, 49% free 3179K/6215K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+21ms
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 194K, 43% free 4063K/7047K, external 3348K/3418K, paused 102ms
D/CallManager(  131): registerPhone(GSM Handler{4055f038})
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.CallLogP
rovider: pid=171 uid=10006 gids={3003, 1015}
W/ActivityManager(   61): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.ussd.IExtendedNetworkService }: not found
W/ActivityManager(   61): finishReceiver called but no pending broadcasts
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 62K, 43% free 4069K/7047K, external 4073K/5086K, paused 256ms
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyServiceState: 3 home null null null  Unknown CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1DefRoam
Ind: -1EmergOnly: false
D/AlarmManagerService(   61): Kernel timezone updated to 0 minutes west of GMT
D/SystemClock(  131): Setting time of day to sec=1320007021
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc com.android.deskclock for broadcast com.android.deskclock/.AlarmInitReceiver: pid=1
85 uid=10019 gids={}
W/SystemClock(  131): Unable to set rtc to 1320007021: Invalid argument
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=radioTurnedOff interfa
ceName=null networkType=0
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=gprsDetached interface
Name=null networkType=0
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 49K, 53% free 2697K/5639K, external 2128K/2137K, paused 477ms
I/ActivityThread(  171): Pub com.android.social: com.android.providers.contacts.SocialProvider
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyServiceState: 0 home Android Android 310260  UMTS CSS not supported -1 -1RoamInd: -1De
fRoamInd: -1EmergOnly: false
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=null interfaceName=nul
l networkType=3
I/ActivityThread(  171): Pub applications: com.android.providers.applications.ApplicationsProvider
D/MccTable(  131): updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=310, mnc=260
D/MccTable(  131): locale set to en_us
D/MccTable(  131): WIFI_NUM_ALLOWED_CHANNELS set to 11
I/WifiService(   61): WifiService trying to setNumAllowed to 11 with persist set to true
I/ActivityManager(   61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=3
4 uiMode=17 seq=4}
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyMessageWaitingChanged: false
D/dalvikvm(  131): GC_CONCURRENT freed 226K, 50% free 2928K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+58ms
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyCallForwardingChanged: false
D/dalvikvm(  171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 406K, 54% free 2613K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+91ms
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 27K, 52% free 2721K/5639K, external 2668K/2681K, paused 381ms
I/ActivityThread(  171): Pub contacts;com.android.contacts: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2
I/ActivityThread(  185): Pub com.android.deskclock: com.android.deskclock.AlarmProvider
D/TelephonyProvider(  131): Setting numeric '310260' to be the current operator
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyDataConnection: state=1 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=simLoaded interfaceName
=null networkType=3
D/dalvikvm(  185): GC_CONCURRENT freed 370K, 54% free 2614K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 5ms+5ms
I/TelephonyRegistry(   61): notifyDataConnection: state=2 isDataConnectivityPossible=true reason=simLoaded interfaceName
=/dev/omap_csmi_tty1 networkType=3
D/Tethering(   61): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 6K, 52% free 2734K/5639K, external 3368K/3387K, paused 188ms
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc com.android.protips for broadcast com.android.protips/.ProtipWidget: pid=201 uid=10
024 gids={}
D/SntpClient(   61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
I/ActivityThread(  171): Pub call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider
I/ActivityThread(  171): Pub user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android.music/.MediaAppWidgetProvider: pid=213
uid=10005 gids={3003, 1015}
D/dalvikvm(   33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 111ms
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 51% free 2780K/5639K, external 4217K/4261K, paused 139ms
D/dalvikvm(   33): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 140ms
D/dalvikvm(   33): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 53% free 2538K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 148ms
D/dalvikvm(  213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 410K, 54% free 2634K/5639K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+4ms
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc com.android.quicksearchbox for broadcast com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchWidgetPr
ovider: pid=221 uid=10002 gids={3003}
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 28K, 51% free 2799K/5639K, external 5345K/5346K, paused 135ms
D/dalvikvm(   61): GREF has increased to 301
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 20K, 51% free 2805K/5639K, external 5417K/6692K, paused 132ms
I/ActivityThread(  221): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.google: com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSuggestionProvid
er
I/ActivityThread(  221): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.shortcuts: com.android.quicksearchbox.ShortcutsProvider
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc android.process.media for broadcast com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadReceiv
er: pid=229 uid=10000 gids={1015, 1006, 2001, 3003}
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_CONCURRENT freed 579K, 45% free 4119K/7367K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 7ms+9ms
I/ActivityThread(  229): Pub media: com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider
V/MediaProvider(  229): Attached volume: internal
W/ActivityManager(   61): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40510a48 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.La
uncher}
D/PowerManagerService(   61): bootCompleted
I/ActivityThread(  229): Pub downloads: com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider
D/VoldCmdListener(   29): volume mount /mnt/sdcard
I/Vold    (   29): /dev/block/vold/179:0 being considered for volume sdcard
D/Vold    (   29): Volume sdcard state changing 1 (Idle-Unmounted) -> 3 (Checking)
I/StorageNotification(  107): Media {/mnt/sdcard} state changed from {unmounted} -> {checking}
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): ** /dev/block/vold/179:0
I/ActivityThread(  229): Pub drm: com.android.providers.drm.DrmProvider
D/OtaStartupReceiver(  131): Not a CDMA phone, no need to process OTA
I/RecoverySystem(   61): No recovery log file
D/dalvikvm(  107): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 159K, 52% free 2723K/5639K, external 2129K/2137K, paused 198ms
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc com.android.mms for broadcast com.android.mms/.transaction.MmsSystemEventReceiver:
pid=244 uid=10015 gids={3003, 1015}
W/WindowManager(   61): App freeze timeout expired.
W/WindowManager(   61): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{406c98c8 token=HistoryRecord{40510a48 com.android.launcher
/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}}
I/ActivityThread(  244): Pub com.android.mms.SuggestionsProvider: com.android.mms.SuggestionsProvider
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc com.android.email for broadcast com.android.email/.service.EmailBroadcastReceiver:
pid=264 uid=10028 gids={3003, 1015}
I/SearchManagerService(   61): Building list of searchable activities
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): ** Phase 1 - Read and Compare FATs
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): Attempting to allocate 2044 KB for FAT
D/dalvikvm(  201): GC_CONCURRENT freed 367K, 54% free 2594K/5575K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/MediaScannerService(  229): start scanning volume internal
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 283K, 44% free 4183K/7367K, external 4373K/5573K, paused 100ms
I/ActivityThread(  264): Pub com.android.email.provider: com.android.email.provider.EmailProvider
I/ActivityThread(  264): Pub com.android.email.attachmentprovider: com.android.email.provider.AttachmentProvider
I/ActivityThread(  264): Pub com.android.exchange.provider: com.android.exchange.provider.ExchangeProvider
D/EAS SyncManager(  264): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
I/SurfaceFlinger(   61): Boot is finished (21020 ms)
I/ARMAssembler(   61): generated scanline__00000177:03010104_00000002_00000000 [ 44 ipp] (66 ins) at [0x44631290:0x44631
398] in 760492 ns
I/ARMAssembler(   61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00000001_00000000 [ 73 ipp] (95 ins) at [0x446313a0:0x44631
51c] in 789741 ns
D/Eas Debug(  264): Logging:
D/EAS SyncManager(  264): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
D/Email   (  264): BOOT_COMPLETED
D/EAS SyncManager(  264): !!! EAS SyncManager, onCreate
D/EAS SyncManager(  264): !!! EAS SyncManager, onStartCommand
D/EAS SyncManager(  264): !!! EAS SyncManager, stopping self
D/EAS SyncManager(  264): !!! EAS SyncManager, onDestroy
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): Attempting to allocate 2044 KB for FAT
D/dalvikvm(  131): GREF has increased to 201
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): ** Phase 2 - Check Cluster Chains
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): ** Phase 3 - Checking Directories
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): ** Phase 4 - Checking for Lost Files
I//system/bin/fsck_msdos(   29): 3 files, 1044466 free (522233 clusters)
I/Vold    (   29): Filesystem check completed OK
I/Vold    (   29): Device /dev/block/vold/179:0, target /mnt/sdcard mounted @ /mnt/secure/staging
D/Vold    (   29): Volume sdcard state changing 3 (Checking) -> 4 (Mounted)
I/PackageManager(   61): Updating external media status from unmounted to mounted
I/StorageNotification(  107): Media {/mnt/sdcard} state changed from {checking} -> {mounted}
D/VoldCmdListener(   29): asec list
I/PackageManager(   61): No secure containers on sdcard
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.and
roid.contacts
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
W/PackageManager(   61): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.andro
id.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings

W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.
settings
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.
providers.contacts
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp in package com.andro
id.providers.contacts
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package c
om.android.development
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.
development
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package
 com.android.development
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package
com.android.development
W/PackageManager(   61): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA in package com.android.email
W/PackageManager(   61): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (prote
ctionLevel=2 flags=0x8be45)
D/MediaScanner(  229):  prescan time: 1340ms
D/MediaScanner(  229):     scan time: 9ms
D/MediaScanner(  229): postscan time: 1ms
D/MediaScanner(  229):    total time: 1350ms
D/MediaScannerService(  229): done scanning volume internal
D/MediaScannerService(  229): start scanning volume external
V/MediaProvider(  229): /mnt/sdcard volume ID: 469043993
V/MediaProvider(  229): Attached volume: external
V/MediaScanner(  229): pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@405b4650
V/MediaScanner(  229): /pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@405b4650
D/MediaScanner(  229):  prescan time: 54ms
D/MediaScanner(  229):     scan time: 2ms
D/MediaScanner(  229): postscan time: 18ms
D/MediaScanner(  229):    total time: 74ms
D/MediaScannerService(  229): done scanning volume external
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 250K, 49% free 3013K/5895K, external 6685K/6692K, paused 52ms
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 109K, 51% free 2928K/5895K, external 4840K/5604K, paused 42ms
I/InputReader(   61): Device reconfigured: id=0x0, name=qwerty2, display size is now 480x800
I/InputManager-Callbacks(   61): No virtual keys found for device qwerty2.
I/ARMAssembler(   61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x44631520:0x4463
16e8] in 1211552 ns
I/ActivityManager(   61): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +37s105ms
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 18K, 50% free 2966K/5895K, external 4698K/5604K, paused 48ms
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0
x10200000 cmp=playn.sample.cute.android/.CuteActivity } from pid 134
I/ActivityManager(   61): Start proc playn.sample.cute.android for activity playn.sample.cute.android/.CuteActivity: pid
=287 uid=10036 gids={}
I/ARMAssembler(   61): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x446316f0:0x4463
18a8] in 453627 ns
D/dalvikvm(  287): Trying to load lib /data/data/playn.sample.cute.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x40514130
D/dalvikvm(  287): Added shared lib /data/data/playn.sample.cute.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x40514130
D/dalvikvm(  287): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/playn.sample.cute.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x40514
130, skipping init
I/WindowManager(   61): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(   61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=3
4 uiMode=17 seq=5}
D/playn   (  287): onResume
I/playn   (  287): notifyVisibilityChanged: 0
D/playn   (  287): Using default sizing.
I/playn   (  287): Screen sized changed to ( 800 , 480)
I/ActivityManager(   61): Displayed playn.sample.cute.android/.CuteActivity: +1s189ms
D/libEGL  (  287): egl.cfg not found, using default config
D/libEGL  (  287): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
W/dalvikvm(  287): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(  287): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
E/AndroidRuntime(  287): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
E/AndroidRuntime(  287):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(  287):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:919)
E/AndroidRuntime(  287):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1264)
E/AndroidRuntime(  287):        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
D/playn   (  287): Using default sizing.
W/ActivityManager(   61):   Force finishing activity playn.sample.cute.android/.CuteActivity
D/playn   (  287): onPause
I/playn   (  287): notifyVisibilityChanged: 4
I/dalvikvm(   61): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 104K, 50% free 2956K/5895K, external 7359K/7393K, paused 43ms
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  134): commitText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  134): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 811K, 45% free 4202K/7623K, external 4768K/5573K, paused 364ms
I/WindowManager(   61): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(   61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=3
4 uiMode=17 seq=6}
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 77K, 49% free 3031K/5895K, external 9236K/9245K, paused 75ms
D/AndroidRuntime(  287): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  287): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
I/Process (  287): Sending signal. PID: 287 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(   61): Process playn.sample.cute.android (pid 287) has died.
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{40767018 SurfaceView paused=false}
E/InputDispatcher(   61): channel '40765870 playn.sample.cute.android/playn.sample.cute.android.CuteActivity (server)' ~
 Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(   61): channel '40765870 playn.sample.cute.android/playn.sample.cute.android.CuteActivity (server)' ~
 Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/WindowManager(   61): WIN DEATH: Window{40765870 playn.sample.cute.android/playn.sample.cute.android.CuteActivity paus
ed=false}
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 24K, 49% free 3035K/5895K, external 8450K/10062K, paused 405ms
E/ActivityThread(  134): Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.L
auncher}
E/ActivityThread(  134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.android.laun
cher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:938)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/ActivityThread(  134):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/InputManagerService(   61): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 287 uid 10036
D/dalvikvm(  134): GC_EXPLICIT freed 215K, 48% free 3162K/6023K, external 8973K/10062K, paused 107ms
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 73K, 46% free 4158K/7623K, external 3511K/4385K, paused 107ms
W/ActivityManager(   61): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4075bfb8 playn.sample.cute.android/.CuteActivity}
```

Comment: Can you provide information on the exception that is thrown? Run `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/platform-tools/adb logcat` to see the logs being generated by the emulator.

Comment: added the logs for the showcase and the cute game, sorry for the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the mailing list for the steps necessary.

In short you have to make sure you are packaging the *.so files. Also run the demos on the device using a USB cable it is much simpler to debug and test. Be warned that there are no input bindings for android AFAIK so you have to implement all key event listeners and take care of a few things. Also there are a few performance bugs with the Box2D library, the performance decreases with time.

PlayN Android state is very early, perhaps too early for adoption. But the guys from threerings are always putting stuff upstream, or you can use their CI service.

Comment: yes, with the latest version pushed in the git master is working, (it was working with the threerings version too) now the examples are deploied in my android device with no errors !