# PlayN 1.6 default maven project deploys but won't run on Android

Tags: playn

I'm having trouble with setting up a new PlayN project and running it on Android. The game compiles, install, but it wont run.

I've created a new project using `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.6`.

And then, without not even touching any single file, I installed it to and Android Emulator instance using `mvn -Pandroid install`

Then, I tried to run the application, but it hanged just after I tried to run it.

I have tried it with two different emulator images, one using Android 2.3.3 ARM, and another using Android 4.2.2 ARM.

The android logcat logs where the folowing

LOG FOR 4.2.2 ARM Android

```
I/ActivityManager(  289): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity} from pid 413
W/WindowManager(  289): Failure taking screenshot for (123x164) to layer 21005
I/Choreographer(  413): Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/SurfaceFlinger(   37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
D/dalvikvm( 1235): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/ActivityManager(  289): Start proc net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android for activity net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity: pid=1235 uid=10047 gids={50047, 1028}
I/dalvikvm( 1235): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 11...
I/Choreographer(  722): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/Trace   ( 1235): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/SurfaceFlinger(   37): createScreenshotSurface failed (Function not implemented)
I/ActivityManager(  289): Config changes=1480 {1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w426dp h294dp 120dpi smll land finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.9}
I/InputReader(  289): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  289): Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 240x320, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 1235): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/SurfaceFlinger(   37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/SurfaceFlinger(   37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
D/libEGL  ( 1235): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
D/libEGL  ( 1235): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/Choreographer( 1235): Skipped 365 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(  722): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6832K, 71% free 2947K/10148K, paused 494ms, total 497ms
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/dalvikvm-heap(  722): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.125MB for 6410576-byte allocation
D/gralloc_goldfish( 1235): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
W/dalvikvm( 1235): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1235): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 87
E/AndroidRuntime( 1235): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
E/AndroidRuntime( 1235):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:863)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1235):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1235):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1235):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
W/ActivityManager(  289):   Force finishing activity net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity
W/WindowManager(  289): Failure taking screenshot for (109x145) to layer 21020
D/dalvikvm(  722): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 10% free 9206K/10148K, paused 378ms, total 379ms
D/dalvikvm(  722): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 9207K/10148K, paused 7ms+5ms, total 116ms
D/dalvikvm(  289): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 199K, 17% free 5336K/6356K, paused 183ms, total 190ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  289): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.435MB for 89296-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  289): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 17% free 5411K/6444K, paused 174ms, total 174ms
W/SurfaceFlinger(   37): createScreenshotSurface failed (Function not implemented)
I/ActivityManager(  289): Config changes=1480 {1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w320dp h401dp 120dpi smll port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.10}
W/ActivityManager(  289): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40d77818 u0 net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity}
I/ActivityManager(  289): Displayed net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity: +2s593ms
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 1027 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  413): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 494 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer( 1235): Skipped 1217 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/InputReader(  289): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  289): Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 240x320, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
I/InputReader(  289): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  289): Device reconfigured: id=0, name='qwerty2', size 240x320, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 360 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 442 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/SurfaceFlinger(   37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
I/Choreographer(  413): Skipped 793 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  413): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(  722): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6828K, 71% free 2948K/10148K, paused 171ms, total 193ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  722): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.125MB for 6410576-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  722): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 10% free 9207K/10148K, paused 24ms+5ms, total 143ms
D/dalvikvm(  289): GC_EXPLICIT freed 85K, 16% free 5444K/6444K, paused 7ms+35ms, total 204ms
I/Choreographer(  722): Skipped 1352 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  289): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/ExchangeService(  661): Received deviceId from Email app: null
D/ExchangeService(  661): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
D/ExchangeService(  661): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
D/ExchangeService(  661): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
D/ExchangeService(  661): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
W/ActivityManager(  289): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
D/ExchangeService(  661): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
W/ActivityManager(  289): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
E/ActivityThread(  661): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff4a0 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread(  661): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff4a0 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/StrictMode(  661): null
E/StrictMode(  661): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff4a0 that was originally bound here
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W/ActivityManager(  289): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40e15c40
E/ActivityThread(  661): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff0a8 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread(  661): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff0a8 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/ActivityThread(  661):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/StrictMode(  661): null
E/StrictMode(  661): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff0a8 that was originally bound here
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/StrictMode(  661):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
D/dalvikvm(  661): GC_CONCURRENT freed 409K, 18% free 2512K/3060K, paused 5ms+26ms, total 76ms
W/ActivityManager(  289): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40e25018
```

LOG FOR 2.3.3 ARM ANDROID

```
I/ActivityManager(   70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity } from pid 227
I/ActivityManager(   70): Start proc net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android for activity net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity: pid=417 uid=10034 gids={}
I/ARMAssembler(   70): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x43bab6f0:0x43bab8a8] in 1571380 ns
D/dalvikvm(  417): Trying to load lib /data/data/net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x40514c78
D/dalvikvm(  417): Added shared lib /data/data/net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x40514c78
D/dalvikvm(  417): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/lib/libplayn-android-nativelib.so 0x40514c78, skipping init
I/WindowManager(   70): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(   70): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=2 layout=17 uiMode=17 seq=6}
I/ActivityManager(   70): Displayed net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity: +1s834ms
D/libEGL  (  417): egl.cfg not found, using default config
D/libEGL  (  417): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
W/dalvikvm(  417): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(  417): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 12
E/AndroidRuntime(  417): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
E/AndroidRuntime(  417):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(  417):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:919)
E/AndroidRuntime(  417):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1264)
E/AndroidRuntime(  417):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
W/ActivityManager(   70):   Force finishing activity net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity
W/InputManagerService(   70): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40952df0 (uid=10034 pid=417)
W/InputManagerService(   70): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4079e5f8
W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4066ab48 net.sf.gnumaru.jogo.android/.JogoActivity}
D/dalvikvm(   70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 208K, 61% free 4205K/10567K, external 809K/1222K, paused 307ms
I/WindowManager(   70): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
I/ActivityManager(   70): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=17 uiMode=17 seq=7}
I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(  224): Switching to locale en_US
D/dalvikvm(  224): GC_CONCURRENT freed 430K, 53% free 2794K/5895K, external 410K/517K, paused 10ms+9ms
D/dalvikvm(   70): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 61% free 4199K/10567K, external 807K/1222K, paused 209ms
I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(  224): Locale change completed in 2358ms
```

I thougth my problem was similar to the one below:

[android artifact built in playn deploied but not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931521/android-artifact-built-in-playn-deploied-but-not-running)

But that question didn't helped me.

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.10 X86_64, the latest android sdk (21.1) and the latest maven (3.0.5)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem.

Android emulator doesn't (or didn't) support OpenGL ES 2.0, and PlayN forces you to use it.

I've tried to deploy and run the application on a real phone and it worked correctly.

Strangely, recent releases (see link below) of the android emulator should support OpenGL ES 2.0 through translation instead of instruction emulation: The emulator GL ES intructions are translated to normal OpenGL instructions and dealt with directly by the host systems GPU, in wich the emulator is running.

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-emulator-now-supports-native-opengl-es2-0/

However, I didn't manage to get it working on Ubuntu 12.10 X86_64, and I haven't tried it on MS Windows yet.